# How do I make a single value update SQL query work with the $wpdb class in Wordpress?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, wordpress

I have a simple `update` query to update a single string value in a table but it is not working for some reason. Is there something wrong with my query or the way I am calling it with `$wpdb`?

```
global $wpdb;
$wpdb->update( 'UPDATE wp_laksh_unique_codes SET status = redeemed WHERE order_id = 418' );
```

Please note that `order_id` column is set to `integer` and `status` column is set to `string`.

P.S. The query is returning `false`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some trial and error, I found the solution.

```
global $wpdb;
$wpdb->update( 'wp_laksh_unique_codes', array( 'status' => 'redeemed'),array('order_id'=>$order_id_marked_int));
```